# how load data from text file to crystal or Stimulsoft

Tags: crystal-reports, report, text-files, stimulsoft

i have text file with data and comma Separator , when call stimulsoft file or crystal report file show data from file text
please help me.

Comment: Could you add an example of what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I found it
I created a form and it reads the data from the text file and sends it for stimulsoft file